# how do I aggregate one column for 2 tests into two columns on one row

Tags: sql

I have a table Called "PassFailMaster" with a PassFail field that is 1 for Pass; 0 for fail. 
I need to count the number of passes and fails and reveal them on the same row. I tried 2 aggregates and a union but I end up with 2 rows for each test type.
Here's a sample of data:

```
CodeName    CodeDesc    TestNumber  PassFail
v1      Vibration   1           0
V1      Vibration   2           0
v1      Vibration   3           1
s1      Shock       4           1
s1      Shock       5           1
s1      Shock       6           0
```

Here's my query

```
SELECT        CodeName, CodeDesc, COUNT(CodeName) AS PassValues, 0 as FailValues
FROM            PassFailMaster
WHERE        (PassFail = 1)
GROUP BY CodeName,  CodeDesc

UNION

SELECT        CodeName, CodeDesc,  0 AS PassValues, COUNT(CodeName) AS FailValues
FROM            PassFailMaster
WHERE        (PassFail = 0)
GROUP BY CodeName,  CodeDesc
ORDER BY CodeName
```

Here's what the data ends up looking like:

```
CodeName CodeDesc   PassValues FailValues
s1      Shock       0           1
s1      Shock       2           0
v1      Vibration   0           2
v1      Vibration   1           0
```

I need the result for passes & fails to end up on one row like this.

```
CodeName CodeDesc PassValues FailValues
s1      Shock       2           1
v1      Vibration   1           2
```

Any ideas?

Thanks - Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conditionally aggregate like so:

```
select      codename
            , codedesc
            , sum(case when passfail = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as pass_values
            , sum(case when passfail = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as fail_values
from        passfailmaster
group by    codename
            , codedesc
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do either of these - Great & Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use your query as a data source for a second query (i.e. use it as a subquery):

```
select 
    codeName, codeDesc, 
    sum(a.passValues) as passValues, sum(a.failValues) as failValues
from
    (
        SELECT
            CodeName, CodeDesc, COUNT(CodeName) AS PassValues, 0 as FailValues
        FROM PassFailMaster
        WHERE (PassFail = 1)
        GROUP BY CodeName,  CodeDesc
        UNION
        SELECT
            CodeName, CodeDesc,  0 AS PassValues, COUNT(CodeName) AS FailValues
        FROM PassFailMaster
        WHERE (PassFail = 0)
        GROUP BY CodeName,  CodeDesc
    ) as a
group by codeName, codeDesc
ORDER BY CodeName
```